# vmware-clarity Type 'ElementRef' is not generic

Tags: angular, highcharts, vmware-clarity

When I use highchart with angular, everything is normal. When I add clr, the error message is as follows:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@clr/angular/popover/common/popover-host-anchor.token.d.ts(2,58): error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
```

Code is here: https://github.com/xchao0213/ngtest
Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Clarity 0.12 requires Angular 6 (see the release notes https://vmware.github.io/clarity/news/0.12.0) and you must be using Angular 5. Update your Angular versions and that will fix your issue.